Non-uniform FFT
I'm looking for a form of a FFT where the samples in the frequency-domain don't represent uniform spaced frequencies. What I would like to get is a frequency-domain with samples that are unevenly spaced, so that e.g. I get a higher resolution at lower frequencies and coarser resolution at higher frequencies.

What algorithms come into play?
Are they as computational effective as the FFT? (e.g. precomputed factors).


might be better asked on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/

See: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93472/non-uniform-fft/93474

look into resampling your unevenly spaced samples into a new uniform spaced set of samples

Have you Googled for the title of your question? It leads to lots, and lots, and lots of resources on this topic, including a Wikipedia page, documentation for functions and packages that implement it, etc.: https://www.google.com/search?q=non-uniform+fft

I just read the first sentence again... there is no mention of non-uniform samples, only of non-uniform frequencies, i.e. the goal appears to be applying the fourier transform for selected frequencies, which may be spaced more densely if they're low frequencies. a usual DFT gives equally spaced frequencies. -- the wording definitely needs improvement.

Sorry for the wrong wording, was more a typo of mine.
